# New slang terms for "old"

Tags: slang

Face it - I'm old (passport-wise - of course I vehemently deny it...). Having faced another incident where oh-so-hip German journalists synthesized "youth language" by themselves, I wonder how a genuine English-speaking youngster would call an old person. Of course, I googled around first, but terms I actually recognized must be, eh, old, like:

- crone: Reclaimed by feminism, but stone-old
- older kocker (sp?): Yiddish, i.e. pre-war
- geezer: Can mean any person now (?)

I'd vote for "codger" (actually a contraction of "coffin dodger"), since it was used in "Teen Titans GO!".

Let's neglect the problem that "in" youth language is always changing with dramatic speed (which was so even before Internet), what would be a slang term for "old" invented not before, say, year 2000, and being in actual use?

Comment: "Boomer". It's short for "baby boomer", and mostly refers to people who are out of touch with youth. In particular, it's a politically charged term used to deride that generation for being oblivious or indifferent to the harm they continue to cause future generations through pollution, capitalism, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Boomer

Among all the words I know for "old person", this one is certainly the one I hear most often (I heard it just yesterday). Derived from the expression [baby boomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_boomers) (itself only first attested in 1963, and in its modern meaning in 1970), *boomer* itself is very recent: [Know Your Meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/ok-boomer) dates "OK, boomer" back to 2015, with it really only gaining traction in 2019. *Boomer* usually has a negative connotation that *baby boomer* does not.

While this term appears in some dictionaries, they tend to define it as an exact synonym for *baby boomer*. This, however, is not entirely how it's used in practice. The term really is used to refer to any old person, even hyperbolically being used to someone older than the speaker or someone who is acting old. [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=boomer) provides definitions mentioning some of these broader usages.

Here is a recent [example from Twitter](https://twitter.com/CarlosR/status/1437882431428861955?s=20) (referring to esports):

> if a 53 yo boomer beats sentinels' Jett Raphael "Shahzam" McDrifter, anybody can

---

None of your suggested words are really used, in my experience, at least not by anyone young.